# Need to select a range of cells based on a cell's value

Tags: excel-formula

Here is a little backstory on what I am trying to do.  First, I am NO Excel expert by an means, but I am a rather quick study and have been able to figure out things as I go.

I created a daily tracking spreadsheet (that I should probably use Access for...) that tracks how many employees worked, type of work they did that day, who didn't work, etc.  Most of the cells are color coded, contain specific text or numbers (a LOT of Conditional Formatting is also applied).

The code that I need help with is currently hard coded to look at a specific column and a specific range of cells.  I need the code to be able to select the range of cells based on the current date, which is listed along the 3rd row from the top.

So instead of this: `=IF(COUNTIF(Y4:Y61....` I need `Y4:Y61` to be a formula that determines what cell the current date is in and calculate in that specific column's range of cells.

thanks in advance

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

For `COUNTIF()` you could simply add the date column being for today as a criterion.

Assuming you want a more general approach you can use the `OFFSET()` formula as you can specify the position and size of the range.

Consider a sheet like this

```
   A             B
1  2015-10-27    1
2  2015-10-27    1
3  2015-10-28    1
4  2015-10-28    2
5  2015-10-28    1
6  2015-10-29    1
```

and today is the 28th of October
You can sum column B by using

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,
            MATCH(TODAY(), A1:A6, 0),
            1,
            COUNTIF(A1:A6,TODAY())))
```

What this does is:

1. move the reference of A1 to the row where your entries from today start.
2. It then takes one column of width.
3. We then give it a row height being the number of entries for today making the formula return 4 today and 1 tomorrow.